# Feature extraction package for time-sereis

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, multivariate-time-series

What are the different packages available for feature extraction when dealing with time-series data ?
I am aware about TSFRESH package. Any other package which is better than the mentioned one.

I have searched different blogs but not sure which one is the best if someone who has does some work on this please provide reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good feature libraries implemented in Python include:

- [tsfresh](https://tsfresh.com)
- [Kats](https://facebookresearch.github.io/Kats/)
- [TSFEL](https://tsfel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [catch22](https://github.com/DynamicsAndNeuralSystems/pycatch22)

Which is "best" probably depends on the problem.